# could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
    
    F = lambda t, s:np.dot(np.array([[0.0303,0,0],[0,1.4666,0],[0,0,0.4078]]), s)
    
    sol = solve_ivp(F, [1, 33],[1,1,1])
```

which works just fine. However, in the definition of the function that I am dealing with, a 3 by 1 vector is deducted at the beginning. But when I include this by typing

```
F = lambda t, s:np.array([[-6.75*(10**-6)],[1.68*(10**-6)],[-5.85*(10**-6)]])-np.dot(np.array([[0.0303,0,0],[0,1.4666,0],[0,0,0.4078]]), s)
```

where now a 3x1 array is deducted, I get the titled error. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by checking the documents and noting that vectorized must be set to True

```
sol = solve_ivp(F, [1, 33],[1,1,1],vectorized=True)
```